# SARIMAX predicted_mean output

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am using SARIMAX to do a forecast model and i would like to add column titles to the output but i'm having trouble. I can work around it by doing .to_csv then reading it back in as a new dataframe before adding the labels but i'd like to be able to do it in one step rather than writing another file.

```
    mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order=(0, 1, 1),
                                seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)
    results = mod.fit()
    pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps = 48)
    pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()

    forecast = pd.DataFrame(pred_uc.predicted_mean, columns = ['TIME', 'column_2'])
```

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 48), indices imply (2, 48)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of reading i ended up finding a solution that suited best because this is iterating and creating a new column for the results each time.

```
compiled_df[column_2] = forecast[0]
compiled_df.index.name = 'TIME'
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

`pred_uc.predicted_mean` is a pandas Series object, associated with an index (e.g. a date index).

You can convert it to a DataFrame, with e.g. `pred_uc.predicted_mean.to_frame()`, but it will still only have one column and an index.

If for some reason you must have it in the form you showed, you could do e.g. the following:

```
pred_uc.predicted_mean.to_frame('column_2').rename_axis('time').reset_index()
```

which would give something like:

```
    time  column_2
0 2009Q4  3.791093
1 2010Q1  1.864600
2 2010Q2  0.680030
3 2010Q3  2.299168
```